# Active Directory to hold user specific configuration

Tags: active-directory

Is it possible that when an application launches that it would look to a certain folder based on the domain user?

An example would be when the application opens for Domain User Fred the application would browse to Drive X:\application folder\Fred but for Domain User Joe the application would browse to Drive Y:\application folder\Joe.

I am working on Multi-Tenant support and trying to use Active Directory to help with partitioning the application.

I want a complete install of the application on Drive X for Group and that Group can only access Drive X, etc for Y and Z.

**Further Explanation:** User Joe belongs to group A and an application for group A is installed at location X.  The application in location X is shared among all users of group A.

There will be multiple groups and the application installed multiple times. With the goal of using Active Directory controlling User Joe's access to the application installed at location X.

Comment: After doing some more reading I think I can also use Shared Folders to redirect to specific Group location.

Comment: Ultimately, you can't control who has access to what mapped drives. That's under the purview of the administrators of each of those shared folders. Does the location need to be a mapped drive? If so, why? Do you need to do this strictly based on group membership? If not, you might want to look into using the %homepath% variable, which is unique and specific to each user.

Comment: I updated the question with a little more information.

Answer (score 1):

Sure - just check the group memberships of the user. If they are member of a role-based Active Directory group that you created for your application, perform the required function. They can even be distribution groups, but they should not be global groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Group Policy for this.

It allows you to map specific drives based on the group membership and/or OU location.

Identify what is common for everyone that needs that specific drive and create the policy accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am more of a Systems person that has done some coding. I did something similar, but the information was stored in the registry. The reason that this would be applicable to you, is that Group Policy has controls that you can push registry settings to a user or computer. Then you have a group policy controlled application, but the information is stored in the registry.

There are some security differences, because the registry is open to local admins. This does not sound like a problem if you are only storing a default file path. I can add more information if needed.

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for.  I will need to test it. The information is application settings for a specific group.